# Downloading USGS map of Nepal seen on New York Times website?

Tags: data, usgs

please take a look at [NYTimes Nepal earthquake map](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/25/world/asia/nepal-earthquake-maps.html?_r=0)

The source is USGS and I spent a lot of time digging around their site... see [usgs map download store](http://www.usgs.gov/pubprod/)
and I am unable to find how you can download such a detailed map of Nepal.

All I see from the usgs site is how you can get US maps.

Does anyone know how to download "non US" maps from the usgs site?

Answer (score 3):

Those are **National Geographic Maps** (basemaps)

Note: You need to select **Terrain** in the Maps Layers on the USGS Earthquake site

[image]

you can view them via USGS via:

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/#%7B%22feed%22%3A%221day_m25%22%2C%22search%22%3Anull%2C%22listFormat%22%3A%22default%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22newest%22%2C%22basemap%22%3A%22terrain%22%2C%22autoUpdate%22%3Atrue%2C%22restrictListToMap%22%3Atrue%2C%22timeZone%22%3A%22utc%22%2C%22mapposition%22%3A%5B%5B27.04200293656626%2C84.19647216796874%5D%2C%5B28.263263279931966%2C87.71209716796874%5D%5D%2C%22overlays%22%3A%7B%22plates%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22viewModes%22%3A%7B%22map%22%3Atrue%2C%22list%22%3Afalse%2C%22settings%22%3Atrue%2C%22help%22%3Afalse%7D%7D

or use the Mapserver from ArcGIS.com which is what is linked in the above example:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserver.arcgisonline.com%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FNatGeo_World_Map%2FMapServer&source=sd

metadata is available from
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer/

disclaimer I have worked on these maps many years ago. (before cloud GIS)

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. I am wondering why NYTImes version seems more sharp and they also have the red borders for mountains I am assuming. Does this mean esri let them edit their own basemap??

Comment: you might be interested in http://nepal.nga.opendata.arcgis.com/

Comment: If you know how to use R, you can easily create those maps: See the R code [here](https://nepalaid.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/plotting-the-earthquake-in-nepal-using-tagr/)